# Hive table count is showing 0 via java JDBC driver

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

I am getting 0 record when i am accessing hive table from JDBC via java. But the same query from beeline it is working fine and showing some number. what could be the reason.?

Comment: Can you add more details? Such as 1. if you are trying to do a SELECT operation - are you seeing data on both JDBC Client and Beeline? 2. Do you see MapReduce job triggered as a part of count execution both in Beeline and JDBC client?

Comment: few tables were showing 0 from jdbc other tables in the same schema is showing some numbers which is matching with beeline count(*) command.

Comment: @Gomz.. How can i check MR jobs are running using JDBC client..

Comment: You can check it in HiveServer2 logs for the respective queryId.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing may be due to stale stats for certain tables in HiveMetastore and if these are referred by the queries.

To test this, you can check by running `set hive.compute.query.using.stats;` on both Beeline-Hive and JDBC Client session to see if the value set for the property   is TRUE or FALSE.

*If TRUE, the query would fetch the statistics from HiveMetastore. (this is usually faster since it fetches the count from HiveMetastore and not by executing a MapReduce job. But it may return incorrect/stale count if the statistics are not updated in HiveMetastore for the table)*

*If FALSE, the query runs a MapReduce as a part of the execution and performs the count from the records present in the data files in HDFS. This is time consuming when compared to the previous one but returns accurate results.*

**Solution:**

1. You can set the property `hive.compute.query.using.stats` to false by running the below statement in Beeline-Hive and JDBC Client sessions. This way, Hive would perform count on the basis of data present in HDFS through a MapReduce job.

```
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=false;
```

OR

2. Compute statistics for the tables manually by running the below statement in either Beeline-Hive or JDBC Client sessions. This will update the HiveMetastore with updated statistics. After this `count(*)` should return correct results in any Hive sessions for that table.

```
ANALYZE TABLE <database_name>.<table_name> COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your inputs. Tried #1 option to set env. variables like below in jdbc parameter :jdbc:hive2://x.x.x.x:7183/;principal=hive/dev.cliennet.com@cliennet.COM?hive.compute.query.using.stats=false.. - getting count value as 0 .. also tried #2 option before executing count query , executed analyze command. getting below exception "org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException Cannot create staging directory "

Comment: Check the complete error and update the question with the efforts you have taken to mitigate the issue.